# What CSS selector can be used to select Bootstrap tooltips?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have finally figured out how to use the Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips, and I am trying to style it. I have asked similar questions about other plugins, and they all ended up being specific CSS selectors. For jScrollPane, the track's selector was `.jspTrack`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjK45/)

My question is, what is the CSS selector for the Twitter Bootstrap tooltips?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: @Jerreck I've already searched through the tutorial, and they don't mention any CSS selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation linked in the comments shows you a sample of the markup that's produced when a tooltip is generated:

> #### Markup
>
> The generated markup of a tooltip is rather simple, though it does require a position (by default, set to `top` by the plugin).
>
> ```
> <div class="tooltip">
>   <div class="tooltip-inner">
>     Tooltip!
>   </div>
>   <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
> </div>
> ```

It should be fairly easy to determine the CSS selector based on this.

There are additional class names attached to `.tooltip` that you can see if you open your browser's DOM inspector and then hover your form element. The one in your example generates the following `.tooltip` element:

```
<div class="tooltip fade right in" style="…">
```

If you need to select only the tooltip belonging to a specific trigger element, that depends on where exactly the tooltip is placed in the DOM. The documentation says (just above the first section I quoted):

> ### Usage
>
> The tooltip plugin generates content and markup on demand, and by default places tooltips after their trigger element.

So the selector would be `.mytrigger + .tooltip` where `.mytrigger` is the form element triggering that tooltip. The DOM position is determined by the `container` option, otherwise it's the default as stated.

Comment: The documentation _also_ says that you can use this: `<element href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip"></element>` with `$('element').tooltip();`

Comment: @JJP: Yes, but that doesn't change how the tooltip is generated. That markup refers to the element that the tooltip is associated with, not the tooltip itself.

Comment: Then why does the tooltip work without the markup you mentioned?

Comment: @JJP The markup mentioned is added when the tooltip event is triggered. Click on the `input` element in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/62B55/), and then inspect the DOM. Notice how it was added with JS?

Comment: I am not using the markup you mentioned in my fiddle, and the tooltip still shows when the element is hovered.

Comment: @JJP: JoshC explains it perfectly.

Comment: @JoshC Ohhh, now I get it. When the event is triggered, it adds the markup, then it destroys the markup, then creates it, etc. Thank you!

Comment: @JJP: Yes, exactly :)